# How to extracts the different land use areas from TIF file within different distances?

Tags: gis, geopandas

I have a TIF format raster data file of land use and a vector point file in SHP format, and want to write a Python script using python libraries like geopandas to create buffers with different distances for the vector points and automatically extracts the different land use areas from TIF file within different distances.  How can I do it?
Thank you very much!

Comment: welcome to stack overflow! please show us what you've tried and where you're stuck. see the guide to [ask], and ideally please try to create a [mre]. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- your question noted that you wanted to extract (clip) data from a GeoTIFF on land usages
- comment then states you want counts of usage pixels associated with buffered points.  This answer does this

  - clip **xarray** to buffered point
  - run analysis on this clipped **xarray** to get counts
  - add usage columns back to **geopandas** data frame as columns

```
import rioxarray
from pathlib import Path
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely.geometry
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# geta raster..
url = "https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/global-land-cover-250m/zipped-tif-files-250m-raster/zipped-tif-files-250m-raster/at_download/file"

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("land-cover.zip")
if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    tif = [f for f in zfile.infolist() if "/" not in f.filename]
    zfile.extractall(path=f.stem, members=tif)

# open the raster
f = list(Path.cwd().joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.tif"))[0]
xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(f)

# reduce size of tif for purpose of dev / testing turnaround speed
devmode = True
if devmode == True:
    _f = f.parent.joinpath("smaller/smaller.tif")
    if not _f.parent.exists():
        _f.parent.mkdir()
    if not _f.exists():
        box = shapely.geometry.box(
            *shapely.geometry.box(*xds.rio.bounds()).centroid.buffer(5 * 10**5).bounds
        )
        xa_cut = xds.rio.clip([box.__geo_interface__], drop=True)
        xa_cut.rio.to_raster(_f)
    xds = rioxarray.open_rasterio(_f)

# some points - cities within bounds of GeoTIFF
gdf = (
    gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
    .to_crs(xds.rio.crs)
    .clip(shapely.geometry.box(*xds.rio.bounds()))
).reset_index(drop=True)

# random distance for each point
np.random.seed(7)
gdf["radius"] = np.random.randint(5 * 10**4, 10**5, len(gdf))
gdf["geometry"] = gdf.apply(lambda r: r["geometry"].buffer(r["radius"]), axis=1)

def land_usage(g):
    xa = xds.rio.clip([g], drop=True)
    xa = xa.where(xa != 0, drop=True)
    counts = xa.groupby(xa).count().drop("spatial_ref").squeeze().to_dict()

    return {
        str(int(k)): v
        for k, v in zip(counts["coords"]["group"]["data"], counts["data"])
    }


# add counts of land use as colums to buffered points
gdf = gdf.join(gdf["geometry"].apply(land_usage).apply(pd.Series))
```

#### output

|  | name | radius | 2 | 4 | 6 | 13 | 16 | 20 | 22 | 14 | 15 | 17 | 19 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Budapest | 99689 | 70923 | 2984 | 2083 | 2342 | 347318 | 1055 | 17074 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 1 | Bratislava | 60742 | 19247 | 8750 | 1085 | 629 | 146807 | 2281 | 6355 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 2 | Vienna | 88467 | 63181 | 66289 | 13330 | 837 | 237979 | 2525 | 8631 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 3 | Prague | 50919 | 2301 | 20483 | 3799 | 15 | 98426 | nan | 5079 | nan | nan | nan | nan |
| 4 | Berlin | 63927 | 1719 | 44207 | 18960 | 21410 | 78925 | 4171 | 18038 | 3337 | 251 | 14070 | nan |
| 5 | København | 84140 | 6460 | 6326 | 11066 | 1732 | 141932 | 133341 | 16274 | 665 | 683 | 11198 | 6 |
| 6 | Warsaw | 52583 | 1998 | 11428 | 9947 | 10557 | 77328 | 1700 | 8836 | 5251 | 109 | 11599 | nan |
| 7 | Vilnius | 78232 | 4826 | 41176 | 23952 | 17708 | 86706 | 3889 | 2637 | 4547 | 62 | 21022 | nan |

Comment: Wow! That is amazing

Answer (score 0):

- have used land use TIF from here https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/global-land-cover-250m
- this really comes down to a few techniques

  - be very consistent with CRS.  Have projected shape file to CRS of TIF
  - given this TIF CRS is in meters **geopandas** / **shapely** `buffer()` makes sense
  - finally use this documented technique https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/masking-by-shapefile.html#

#### full code

```
from pathlib import Path
from zipfile import ZipFile
import requests
import rasterio, rasterio.mask, rasterio.plot
import geopandas as gpd
import shapely
import numpy as np
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# geta raster..
url = "https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/global-land-cover-250m/zipped-tif-files-250m-raster/zipped-tif-files-250m-raster/at_download/file"

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("land-cover.zip")
if not f.exists():
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True, headers={"User-Agent": "XY"})
    with open(f, "wb") as fd:
        for chunk in r.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
            fd.write(chunk)
    zfile = ZipFile(f)
    tif = [f for f in zfile.infolist() if "/" not in f.filename]
    zfile.extractall(path=f.stem, members=tif)

# open the raster
src = rasterio.open(list(Path.cwd().joinpath(f.stem).glob("*.tif"))[0])

# some points - cities within bounds of GeoTIFF
gdf = (
    gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path("naturalearth_cities"))
    .to_crs(src.crs)
    .clip(shapely.geometry.box(*src.bounds))
).sample(15)

# random distance for each point
gdf["geometry"] = gdf["geometry"].apply(lambda p: p.buffer(random.randint(10**5, 5*10**5)))

# shapes to mask raster
shapes = [f["geometry"] for f in gdf["geometry"].__geo_interface__["features"]]

# mask the raster, with points buffered to distance
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(src, shapes, crop=True)
out_meta = src.meta

# save and reload masked raster
out_meta.update({"driver": "GTiff",
                 "height": out_image.shape[1],
                 "width": out_image.shape[2],
                 "transform": out_transform})

f = Path.cwd().joinpath("land-cover/masked")
if not f.exists(): f.mkdir()
f = f.joinpath("land-maksed.tif")
with rasterio.open(f, "w", **out_meta) as dest:
    dest.write(out_image)
msk = rasterio.open(f)

# let's have a look at what we've done..
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# transform rasterio plot to real world coords
extent=msk.bounds
ax = rasterio.plot.show(msk, extent=extent, ax=ax)
```

#### output

Different size circles as have used random buffer radius of random points.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I still have a question. How to count and output the pixels number of each of masked raster for each of colors (represents different land use types)? Thanks again.

Comment: that's IMHO quite a different question,  have provided a second answer for that